# AWS VPC: restricting user to create/delete its own VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc

Conceptually is it possible to create an IAM policy such that developer can only create/delete its own 50-net (e.g. 50.10.0.0/16) VPC?  Or do we usually rather having the network admin to allocate the VPC to developer coming on board?

I want to organize the org such that

User : VPC

dev-1: 50.10.0.0/16

dev-2: 50.20.0.0/16

dev-3: 50.30.0.0/16

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A CIDR range starting with `50.` is publicly routable and **should generally be avoided**. It is better to allocate ranges from these address blocks, which are intended for private use:

- 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255

See: [What Is a Private IP Address & What Are the Ranges?](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-private-ip-address-2625970)

**Multiple VPCs can be created with the same CIDR range**, so each developer could have their own range of private IP addresses that overlap each other. It simply means that they cannot be (easily) joined together.

It is **not possible** to restrict a user's CIDR range when creating a VPC.

See: [Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 API Actions - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html)

You can, however, **restrict which actions they may use**. So, you might provide them with a VPC, **deny** permissions to create other VPCs, but allow them to create/delete **subnets** *within* the VPC.

See: [Controlling Access to Amazon VPC Resources - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_IAM.html)